# Junit 5 for Gson used in aem servlet

Tags: java, gson, aem, junit5

I have a java pojo class "IdDetails.java" with Getter/Setter methods. I am mapping this pojo in another Servlet using Gson.fromJson . When I am instantiating Gson in Junit5 Test Class it is giving the below error ----
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.(java.util.Map)'     at com.google.gson.Gson.(Gson.java:209)
    at com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.create(GsonBuilder.java:626)**

Can anyone help in writing Junit5 test case to cover this specific line --

IdDetails idDetails = new Gson().fromJson(req.getReader(),IdDetails.class);

The codes are provided below -

IdDetails class -

```
public class IdDetails {
    private String fb;
    private String gd;
    private String apple;

    public String getFb() {
        return fb;
    }

    public void setFb(String fb) {
        this.fb= fb;
    }

    public String getGd() { return gd; }

    public void setGd(String gd) {
        this.gd= gd;
    }

}
```

SlingPostServlet -

```
@Override
protected void doPost(final SlingHttpServletRequest req, final SlingHttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException 
{
        IdDetails idDetails = new Gson().fromJson(req.getReader(),IdDetails.class);
        //other codes .....
}
```

I am beginner in Junit5 . Please help me in writing the test case.

Comment: Probably you somehow have multiple versions of Gson on your classpath, see also the [troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/Troubleshooting.md#nosuchmethoderror-when-calling-gson-methods); try `Gson.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` and `Class.forName("com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor").getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()`. They should both report the same JAR file.

Comment: Thanks Marcono , for the reply but we are using single version of GSON only.

Comment: We want how we can write junit for this particular line or either we can bypass this particular set of line to continue with our junit.
IdDetails idDetails = new Gson().fromJson(req.getReader(),IdDetails.class);

Comment: What I meant was that your unit test execution is incorrectly configured and loads two versions of Gson, not because you have declared Gson two times but because a tool or library you are using adds a second version of Gson. Otherwise you would not experience the `NoSuchMethodError`, because the JARs published by Gson are complete. Please edit your unit test to run the code shown above and prints its output to console to find out where the Gson classes are loaded from. If different locations are printed it might help you to find the underlying cause for the issue.

Comment: You can check classpaths via `-X` flag in Maven, for instance.